# prestashop unwanted products in order

Tags: prestashop, product

I faced some weird problem. Until now everything worked perfectly but last few days I braking myself with solving this.

Problem is that when order comes I have there unwanted products. I can't figure it out why.

I have new order with one product and order is sent with only that product. But in orders backoffice I have more products in that order that I didn't add to my cart.

The interesting one is that one time I had products that are samples in new prestashop installation (iPod nano). I don't even have this product in my catalogue.

So did anybody faced this problem and find a solution.

P.S. the mail that is sent to customer doesn't have this product, But PDF invoice has this unwanted product and don't have product ordered.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  As it stands, there are a number of very general questions that you've posed.  It's too broad for people to be of help.  Please come back with more specific questions, show code as appropriate, and give people the most information you can about where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it few days ago. Problem was with plugin for deleting orders from PS, because in database information stayed and this was doubled. I had two rows with same ID.

Solved